# Magento product url not working after magento upgrade from 1.5 to 1.8

Tags: module, url, url-rewrite, reindex

I have upgraded magento from 1.5 to 1.8, everything is working fine apart from custom URL. 
Custom product URL is not working even after reindexing everything.

is there any way we make old custom URL workable in Magento 1.8.

Comment: Check for products if they are having same url keys. And if there are products like that, first of all change their url keys and make them unique.

Comment: From the information in the comments, [this question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/magento-core-url-rewrite-table-excessively-large) is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your .htaccess file has been overwritten.
Compare your new .htaccess with your backup and make sure your rewrite rules are in there.

Comment: Site is running on ngnix server so .htaccess does not matter

Comment: Does your rewrite work with index.php in it? eg: yoursite.com/index.php/category-rewrite-url

Comment: No. The problem is this that its product id in end of request when i do url reindex. for exmaple miele-universal-vacuum-cleaner-bags-fits-all-miele-barrel-vacuums-af375-2146 request path should be miele-universal-vacuum-cleaner-bags-fits-all-miele-barrel-vacuums-af375

Comment: thats not the product id in the end, the url index adds an incremental value at end of url because of a bug which increases with every reindex