# magento url rewrite prevent -1 or -2

Tags: url-rewrite

I have a category created which contains url key as - "sofa" and url generated is "sofa.html". URL rewrites system record generated as follows :

```
ID Path : category/5
Request path : sofa.html
Target Path : catalog/category/view/id/5
```

Now I want to run one of the custom module over that url(sofa.html) so I deleted system url rewrites and added custom url rewrites from the backend as follows :

```
ID path : alternate-sofa
Request path : sofa.html
Target path : alternate-sofa
```

So when I run sofa.html from the browser, I got the expected page from the custom module and it resolves the issue removing custom rewrites after reindexing, though after reindexing new system record added as follows :

```
ID path : category/5
Request path : sofa-1.html
Target path : catalog/category/view/id/5
```

Now, I am having issue as follows : On the page, I am listing out categories on left side which contains category url as "sofa-1.html" which is displaying my category layout instead of custom module. How to overcome this issue? I don't want to create sofa-1.html, sofa-2.html, onwards.

Edit :
I refereed http://jc-designs.net/blog/2012/09/magento-adding-cms-pages-to-the-main-navigation/ and http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar but when I set 301(permenant), url changed from "sofa.html" to "alternate-sofa" which is not expected url in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You cant simply prevent this, as there are cases, where it could make sense, like when you have products whith the same url key.

Additionally this is caused by a bug in magento, which has severel possible bugfixes, some of them described in [Magento core_url_rewrite table excessively large](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/magento-core-url-rewrite-table-excessively-large/33002)

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled -1 or -2 in the url's is making sure all index processes are done or set on manual index. Then in the URL Rewrite manager I search for all requested paths with -1 and remove them. Reindex catalog URL Rewrites and they should be resolved.

Comment: After reindexing, it has been added again because "sofa.html" already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the settings in admin under **System -> Configuration -> Catalogue -> Catalogue -> Search Engine Optimisation -> Category URL Suffix** - This should be **".html"**, you just need to change it to **BLANK**. Once done then delete all the entries from **core_url_rewrite** table for all the categories using the following query -:

> DELETE FROM core_url_rewrite WHERE product_id IS NULL AND LENGTH(category_id)>0
>
> **N.B - Please take DB back up prior to run any update/insert/delete queries on production server**

Hope it helps

Cheers
S