# Can I Delete The Thousands Of URL Rewrites?

Tags: magento-1, redirect

I am wanting to add redirects from old site URL to new site URLs however when I go into URL Rewrite Management there are over 8,000 records there already. Can I delete these?

Most of them are in the following format:
ID  Path: product/1483
Request Path: brilliant-whisper-300-1483.html
Target Path: catalog/product/view/id/1483

I'm hesitant about deleting them if they are necessary...

Answer (score 4):

The answer is - as always - it depends :)

In general, you can truncate (not delete!) the table `core_url_rewrite`. If it is empty, your SEO URLs like `brilliant-whisper-300-1483.html` will not work for the time being. But if you do a full reindex of the catalog URL rewrites, these URLs will be generated again, so that your SEO URLs should work again.
If you struggle with a very big `core_url_rewrite` table, then have a look at [this Magento StackExchange question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/17553/142).

What **can** cause problems is if you did one of the following:

1. You changed the URL key of a catalog/product and ticked the box `Create Permanent Redirect for old URL`. Assumed you changed the URL key from `my-old-product-name` to `my-new-product-name`. Then, when this box is ticked, a rewrite from `my-old-product-name.html` to `my-new-product-name.html` will be created in the `core_url_rewrite` table. If you truncate the table, this rewrite will be gone, so that your old product URL will not work any more.
2. You created custom URL rewrites under `Catalog - URL Rewrite Management`. These custom URL rewrites will also be gone if you truncate `core_url_rewrite`.

Comment: Thank you for giving a more objective answer. If you're worried about 301 redirects for pages whose URL keys have been changed after Google has indexed the pages and they've been linked to elsewhere, you get a little less cavalier about just blindly truncating this table. Only in 1.7 and 1.8 where there's a category save bug, do you get concerned about "excessive" numbers of entries. SUPEE-389_EE_1.12.0.2_v1.patch

Answer (score 1):

for me with 1.9.2 this does a temporary fix. Simons link is more permanent..check it out.
So instead of truncating all of the data, especially if your custom urls are THE most important function of the core rewrites, you can query the database to omit custom url rewites and to show only the system url rewites. Then you can delete your system url rewrites. However, this will cause problems IF you still NEED your old urls, you will lose your old URL's this way.
Some people do not need the old url's. Its a quick dirty way to clean that rewrite table.
as always export backups FIRST.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate `core_rewrite` table after doing a backup of that table. That should do the job.

Comment: And after you do that, have him tell you how to get the ones you need back... They're there for a reason and SEO friendly URLs **require** them. You may be fixing a conceived problem by creating a real problem.

Comment: @FiascoLabs you can regenerate the required rows executing "reindex".

Comment: Not the ones you hand entered...