# how do i delete urls of other stores in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite

Can anyone please let me know how do i keep urls of english stores and mass delete urls of Russian, French, German stores etc? because at the moment i have 8 Million URLs and how do i stop generating urls of Russian, French, German stores? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin->System->Manage Stores`

Then click on the Store View Name (e.g. FR for France) and change the status to disabled.

That will remove the non-English stores appearing on the web.

Comment: Thanks, All the other stores except english are disabled but I can see French, Russian etc urls in the URL Rewrite Management so please tell me how do i delete them? Thanks

Comment: There are a few answers about this topic on here. E.g. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34670

Comment: Disabled all the stores except english but url's are still generating for all the stores (French, German, Russian ect.) after reindexing catalog_url rewrites. can anyone tell me how do i stop generating urls for other stores. Thanks