# Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: catalog, url-rewrite, sql, reindex

Quite often we get the following error in Magento when we try to make a change to one of our Categories.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1205] Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting
>   transaction, query was: UPDATE `catalog_category_entity` SET
>   `entity_type_id` = ?, `attribute_set_id` = ?, `parent_id` = ?,
>   `created_at` = '2015-10-30 11:24:57', `updated_at` = '2016-11-27
>   07:33:07', `path` = ?, `position` = ?, `level` = ?, `children_count` =
>   ? WHERE (`entity_id`=250)

It seems to only be occurring after we have moved around or reorganised a category and I can see from **System > Index Management** that **Catalog URL Rewrites** is still being processed.  Once the indexing is finished we can make changes to categories, but this is a recurring problem which really slows things down.

I've checked **Catalog > URL Rewrite Management** and we have almost 500,000 rewrites, we have 4 store views, 350,000 plus of them are custom although we obviously did not create them all.  I believe this is what is slowing everything down.

I'm not sure what to do here, if I truncate the **core_url_rewrite** database table with `TRUNCATE TABLE 'core_url_rewrite';` and re-index **Catalog URL Rewrites** in **System > Index Management** will that fix it?  Is there anything I should be aware of before I cary try this?  I'll do a table & db back up first of course and test it in a local environment.

Comment: You can get refrence from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is because the transaction is reaching its timeout period. If you did not set this in your `my.cnf` [the default is 50 seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) I would highly recommend you look at your sever settings to ensure that they are optimized for your database using tools such as [MySQLTuner](http://mysqltuner.com/)

I have the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` set to  `7200` (2 hours) in a store with 500k products with 2 store views.

Example to add or change in `my.cnf`

`innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 7200`

**DO NOT TRUNCATE.... yet**

When you "moved around or reorganised a category" Magento will keep the references to these original links (hence the massive amount of links and 4 store views as well) and redirect them for visitors / bots / search engines that have book marked or indexed these pages.This can negatively affect your SEO, when you `truncate` they will receive a `error 404` message.  My personal recommendation is BEFORE doing major changes to the structure, ensure that nothing of the sort has been done for at least a month, then `truncate` then do your restructuring. This will cut down enormously on the size of your **URL Rewrites**

Since you've already re-arranged your categories, the best thing to do now is wait for a month to give visitors / bots / search engines the time to update the links --- then purge.

Also checkout:[Magento core_url_rewrite table excessively large](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/magento-core-url-rewrite-table-excessively-large)