# `core_url_rewrite` Table optimization

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, optimization

I think `core_url_rewrite` is built in the wrong way:

- why it contains records for not visible products ( all simple associated to the configurable for example )
- why it contains records for every storeview even if the `request_path` (`url_key`/`url_path`) for a product/category is the same for every `storesview` ?

I actually have 394415 records on this table ( my store has 28120 products and 7 `storeviews` ), if I could solve the above 2 point I think the table would be 10 times smaller.

Anybody worked on this before ?

Comment: it is but that question points to another problem with `url_rewite`, the solutions proposed there has been already implemented on my store few months ago

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions. 
You can follow that solutions 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18690/49821

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344354/magento-url-indexing-and-core-url-rewrite-table

http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/magento/how-we-solved-magento-core_url-issues-once-and-for-all

With this you can  check what exactly problem is in your case.

Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately those solutions do not address the problems described in the question, thanks anyway for adding these links