# Magento 1.9.3 re-indexing page and URL Issue

Tags: magento-1.9

Every time Magento 1.9.3  re-indexing page and **URL** automatically increases

every time when I run **re-indexing**,  URL Rewrite Management increases ???

even product or fix

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aitnr.png]

Comment: Hello maybe this answer relate to you: [stack answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18690/33398)

Answer (score 0):

> There are several reasons why this may happen. One of the more is when
>   you have several products with the same URL key.
>
> Example: If you have two products both named "Test" with both products
>   having the same URL key "test". Magento will create two URL rewrites:
>   one for test.html and one for test-2.html. If you re-run the Rewrite
>   Indexing process, Magento will start creating a further redirect for
>   the test-2.html URL and so on. It happens pretty often, especially
>   with stores having configurable products with many simple products
>   sharing the same name (e.g. clothes with different sizes and colors).

**To Fix**

> Open up phpMyAdmin, create a backup of your Magento database, and
>   flush the Magento table core_url_rewrite (so that it becomes totally
>   empty). Immediately afterwards, refresh the Catalog Url Rewrites under
>   Index Management. This will regenerate all URLs.