# core_url_rewrite is too big

Tags: magento-1.9, database, url-rewrite, reindex

I have an issue with my Magento's database (Magento 1): in few days, doing several times the reindexing process, the table '`core_url_rewrite`' weighs about `10 GB` and the server stops to work. Then, both the frontend and the backend become unable to be reached.

How can I solve it?

Comment: I hope my answer will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php

around  line 807

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Url::getProductRequestPath()` ]

**From:**

```
if ($product->getUrlKey() == '' && !empty($requestPath)
   && strpos($existingRequestPath, $requestPath) === 0
)
```

**To:**

```
if (!empty($requestPath)
           && strpos($existingRequestPath, $requestPath) === 0
)
```

**Step 1:** Truncate

Truncate the `core_url_rewrite` table

**Step 2:** Reindex & Flush Caches

Initiate the re-indexing process on Core URL Rewrites.
Thereafter, you'll want to flush the Magento cache & storage cache.

`System` → `Cache Management` → `Flush Magento Cache`

`System` → `Cache Management` → `Flush Cache Storage`

You'll notice if you re-run the indexer, the table should stay constant in size (unless you've added more products inbetween or if you have duplicate category names).

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/magento-core-url-rewrite-table-excessively-large)