# Delete Magento 1.9 Core URL Rewrites

Tags: magento-1.9, database, url-rewrite

I need to delete/truncate the Magento 1.9 core URL rewrites which are **older than 3 months of core_url_rewrite table** in Database.

What's the exact SQL query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

URL rewrite tables (*both Community and Entrerprise*) don't store "created at" or "updated at" values in Magento 1.9.x or 2.x. Without timestamps I wouldn't think it's possible to actually use time as a condition for deletion

Answer (score 0):

You could just:

```
truncate core_url_rewrite;
```

And then do a reindex on url rewrites.

**BUT**, I'd follow this question: [Magento core_url_rewrite table excessively large](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/17553/4276) and its accepted answer to prevent my table from storing too-oo much data.

Also take a look at this free extension: https://www.magecloud.net/marketplace/extension/dn-d-patch-index-url-1/. It controls the url rewrite reindex process and skips the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to delete the URL rewrites **older than 3 months**. Is it possible?