# Core URL re-write table - delete URL entries for deleted products

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, product-urls, catalog-url-rewrite

We are on Magento Version 1.9.3.7 and have been using Magento for a few years now. When we moved our site to the live site from the development site, we deleted all the development products but looks like the URL's created in the development site in the URL re-write table did not get deleted and are in the live site's table.

Over a period of time, this table as you all know has grown and now as 1.5 million records in it.

In our live site, I see that the system generated product ID (under Catalog --> Manage Products) starts at 2800. I assume that 2800 products were added during development and testing.

Using the SQL query below - shows that there are 500,000 records
SELECT * FROM `core_url_rewrite` WHERE `product_id` <> 'NULL' AND `product_id` < 2800 AND `product_id` > 0;

My question is, is it safe to go ahead and delete these 500,000 records from the URL re-write table as these URL's are of no use since there are no associated products related to the URL. Will there be any SEO impact or any other issues that you foresee?

At least it will solve part of the problem for us.

Your advice and suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you have so many entries because of [this bug](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18690/3024) and it's totally unrelated to your Dev products.

Once you delete products and reindex there shouldn't be any entries for these items in the `core_url_rewrite` table.

Comment: Yes, but the database does show half a million records with product ID's that are non-existent (based on the SQL statement I mentioned above). So in this case, do you think it will be OK to just delete the half million records? Thx much

Comment: Truncating core_url_rewrite should not cause any problems as Magento will re-build once you re-index.  The only issue may be if you have any custom re-writes as these will also be deleted.